# Why user autometically authenticated in django test case?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, testcase

```py
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
APICLIENT = APIClient()
from factory_djoy import UserFactory

class TestAccount(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.user = UserFactory()
    def test_print_name(self):
        print(self.user.is_authenticated)
        # do something here
```

why **print(self.user.is_authenticated)** is True. I have tried to create a user using simply **User.objects.create** it also returns the same as is_authenticated to **True**.

My understanding is that it should be not be **True** before doing **login** or **force_authenticate.** What am I doing wrong or is my understanding not correct?

Comment: `.is_authenticated` does *not* mean that the user is authenticated on the server side. All users have `is_authenticated = True`, it is used to make a distinction between a `User` object, and the `AnonymousUser`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.is_authenticated` does *not* mean that the user is authenticated on the server side. All `User` objects have `is_authenticated = True`, it is used to make a distinction between an [**`User`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) object, and the [**`AnonymousUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser).

Indeed, by default if you look for `request.user`, it will either return an `AnonymousUser` object if there is no user attached to the setting, or a `User` object if the session is bound to that user.

For the builtin `User` model, `.is_autenticated` [will thus always return `True` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.0.x/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L89-L95):

> ```
> @property
> def is_authenticated(self):
>     """
>     Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
>     authenticated in templates.
>     """
>     return True
> ```

You can however define your own custom user model, and define a more sophisticated test: for example only users with `is_active` can be authenticated, or users can only be authenticated if these have been active the last two months for example.

If you write in a view `if user.is_authenticated`, it will thus for the builtin user model make a distinction between an `AnonymousUser` (that will return `False`), and a `User`. But you can define a custom user model with a custom implementation.